# How to reset a datepicker search?

Tags: search, mobile-application, datetimepicker

I'm facing a difficult call on how to correctly implement a datepicker search on a native mobile App. The [library](https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker) which I want to use doesn't have any reset functionality. For now, I have multiple ideas on how to do so:

- Create a clear button, but there is another input text field so it will be unclear what it's going to reset
- Create a tag with a cross that replaces the button of the datepicker

Which idea would be better? Is there another way?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it a date range or just a single day selector?

Comment: Could you maybe demonstrate both ways? The way that I hear it, it seems understandable, but I would like to see it visually :)

Comment: I updated the question with pictures

Comment: Why is from and to separated? Because when you have the functionality of "clearing," you don't necessarily just clear one or the other, you are clearing both. What's the point of clearing one or the other? The user can just re-click a date?

Comment: The clear button is for both "from" and "to".

Answer (score 1):

I think that clearing the date **is not a part of date selection** and should not be hidden inside a date selector.

The choice between having a date set and no date set is logically at the higher level than selecting the specific date. Only after making a decision to set a date, the selector should appear, allowing User to further specify it.

Therefore, clearing the date should not be placed within the date selector but outside of it, a step before. I think that the second approach would be more appropriate.

Comment: I agree with your point of view. On another hand, wouldn't be easy for the user if he sees the "clear" functionality inside the datepicker when choosing the date ? It has the advantage of letting more space to the list to be shown, which is of a notable importance